# Saving raw http request in database

Tags: mysql, node.js, logging

We need to save account activity in our database so that the admin can see each user activity and perform basic level debugging. Is it a good idea to save raw HTTP requests in MySQL database or should it be parsed?

Currently, I am having a following table

```
id
userID,
SubjectType,
message,
timestamp,
IP,
UserAgent
```

I also wants to save raw HTTP request and response so that debugging can be made easy incase user faces some errors.

We are using Node JS as our backend API

Answer (score 0):

originalUrl it is raw url save it in db , you should update user activity field in the db with Date.now() . You can create array of strings in db to save all request to track activity , i suggest you also use knex as a ORM .